# Which is the best python module for command execution

Tags: python, linux, shell, command

I want to perform various `Linux` commands/operations using python script. I will be using the output, verifying/processing it and continue with some more commands execution in my script, may be remote execution also sometimes.

I have tried with both `os` and `subprocess` modules. The caveat here is, I am not able to combine both of them i.e. system calls or commands executed from one module does not affect "program/python" environment variables rather only considered by that particular module.

For. ex.

```
os.chdir(dirname)
os.system(cmd)
# p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Now, here changes from `os.chdir` are not useful for subprocess call. We have to stick with any one of them. If I use `subprocess`, I have to pass/create shell commands for it.

---

**Added:** `cwd=` is a solution for `subprocess.Popen` but every time I would have to pass option `cwd` as argument to future commands, if they all should be run from that dir

---

Is there a better way where we can use both of these modules together?

Or

Is there any other better module available for command executions.

Also I would like to know "Pros-Cons/Caveats" of both these modules.

Comment: @jozefg I have visited that question earlier. It is more about how I can execute one single command, and not for whole script. My question is for multiple commands if I want to combine functions from both `os` and `subprocess`, how can I do that?

Comment: If you are using internal shell commands in a Python script, you are doing it wrong (you should've sticked with a `sh` script). If you want to run other executables, `subprocess` is the correct module. All your questions could be answered by anyone (including you) that properly read the `subprocess` documentation.

Comment: Have a look at `envoy`: https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy  `subprocess` can be a bit counter-intuitive at first, `envoy` simplifies things for the use-case of shell scripting, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`os.system` always runs `/bin/sh`, which parses the command string. This can be a security risk if you have whitespace, `$` etc. in the command arguments, or the user has a shell config file. To avoid all such risks, use `subprocess` with a list or tuple of strings as the command (`shell=False`) instead.

To emulate `os.chdir` in the command, use the `cwd=` argument in `subprocess`.

Comment: `os.system` and `os.chdir` were more of examples. Lets say if I want to run command with different user. I have `os.setuid()` and in subprocess I would have to do `su user cmd`.

Comment: Also with subprocess every time I would have to pass `cwd=` argument  to future commands, if they all should be run from that dir.